# GridLayout columns do not appear right

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout

I tried to configure a grid layout with 2 rows and 2 columns. But each element here occupies the entire width of the screen, while the second column is outside the screen. Please suggest what am I doing wrong here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorTheme"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/moodsGridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="2">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/brewtv_logos" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/brewtv_logos" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/brewtv_logos" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/brewtv_logos" />
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It seems quite obvious, to me, that if a column's width is set to `match_parent`, the other columns will have no room left. Try using dicrete dp values for your ImageButtons.

Comment: Since the element is enclosed inside GridLayout and row span of each underlying element will still be 1, it is supposed to occupy only half the screen, right? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Try. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I've tried the same dynamically, the result is as expected. But the layout xmls are causing some trouble.

Comment: Then keep the dynamically generated one and set the xml values to either `0dp` or `wrap_content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

for Uniform width column and row in Gridlayout use:

```
android:layout_columnWeight="1"    
android:layout_rowWeight="1"
```

use this layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/moodsGridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="2">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]